# MVC view button click event , Pass AngularJs object to another MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to pass AngularJs object to another Controller when button click event on view.

**CHTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="hotel in respData.hotels">
   <button type="button" class="btn" data-ng-click="setTab(hotel.code)">Check Availability
</button></div>
```

**Script**

```
$scope.setTab = function (hotelcode) {
   var url = 'Hotel';
   url += '?HotelCode=' + hotelcode ' 
   window.location.href = url;}
```

Now i'm passing one value only. I want to pass **hotel** **object** as a parameter.
Is their way to do that?

Comment: Why are you using window.location to change url , why you are not using angular routing ?

Comment: I'm using mvc routing. if their way to combined anguler and mvc routing?

Comment: this blog may be helpful for you then http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/mvc-routing-with-angularjs-routing/

Comment: Thank you, That's very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass your whole Hotel object to your first controller and then make use of $emit or $broadcast in order to send that object to another controller. Here's a short example:

One.html

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

 <script>
 var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
 $stateProvider.state('two',{
   url: '/two',
   templateUrl: "two.html",
 })
 })

 app.controller("Parent", function ($scope, $state) {
   $scope.send = function (msg) {
     $scope.$broadcast('eventName', { message: msg });
     $state.go('two')
   };
 });

 app.controller("Child", function ($scope) {
   $scope.$on('eventName', function (event, args) {
     $scope.message = args.message;
     console.log($scope.message);
   });
 });

 </script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <h1> Index Page </h1>

  <!---
  Look at these div tags here, $broadcast is used to transfer content from
  Parent to Child Controllers only and $emit for Child to Parent Controller
  !--->

  <div ng-controller = "Parent" >
    <button ng-click = send('Hello')> Send Hello</button>
         <div ng-controller = "Child" class="container" ui-view> </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Two.html

```html
<body ng-app="app">
    <span> Recieved : {{message}}</span>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm try that before. return null object on other view. Is there sample with 2 html pages?

Comment: Try the code I gave above, just send your hotel object instead of msg to the Child Controller.

Comment: Make 2 different html files and copy the above code and try running it.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load second html page Cross origin requests. how can i correct that?

Comment: Either use firefox or make a node server and deploy these web pages on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$state.go('toState',object);
```

You can use `$state.go` to send object values to another controller if you are using `ui-router` if not you can use emit and broadcast see details  [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1949)

Working plnkr of broadcast can be found [here](http://embed.plnkr.co/wq5q4i/)

```
app.controller('Parent', function($scope) {
  $scope.message="";
   $scope.emitedmessage="";
  $scope.clickevent=function(){
    $scope.$broadcast('transfer',{message:$scope.message});
  }
    $scope.$on('transferUp',function(event,data){
    console.log('on working');
     $scope.emitedmessage=data.message;
  });
});

app.controller('Child',function($scope){
  $scope.message="";
   $scope.broadcastmessage=""
  $scope.$on('transfer',function(event,data){
     $scope.broadcastmessage=data.message;
  });
  $scope.clickevent=function(){
    $scope.$emit('transferUp',{message:$scope.message});
  }
});
```

Comment: Are your sure that OP is using `ui.router`?